# Returning the value of the last iterators used in a double for loop

Tags: function-construction

This is a basic question - I'm just unfamiliar with Mathematica. For a given $n$, I'd like to find integral $b$ and $k$ such that $bn + k^2$ is a perfect square. I know that $k$ and $b$ are less than $50$. Here's what I've tried:

```
perfectSquare[n_] := Sqrt[n] == Round[Sqrt[n]];
KandB[n_] := {k, b}
for[k = 0, k < 50, k++,
  for[b = 0, b < 50, b++,
   perfectSquare[b*n + k^2]]];
KandB[n]
```

This returns $\{1,1\}$ regardless of what $n$ is. I assume there's some issue with the syntax I used when defining the KandB function. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why not use FindInstance instead, e.g. for `n=21` do `FindInstance[
 21 b + k^2 == m^2 && k < 50 && b < 50, {b, k, m}, PositiveIntegers]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is certainly a good start, and your question is quite valid.
It seems to me like you have a more Python-esque/C++ approach to coding, which is by all means valid in MMA. There are a few things that you need to know:

---

### 1. Built-in functions are always capitalised

This is true for the `For` function as well. I have taken the liberty to amend this in your post, so now your For loop should work to do what you *programmed* it to do.

### 2. Your defined functions of `perfectSquare` and `KandB` are partially incomplete

Your perfectSquare function returns a binary response as well from how it has been constructed. Ideally you want to program it so that it returns the values and use the function $b n + n k^2$ as a *criterion for selection*.

[@lericr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283344/20155)'s solution very elegantly demonstrates that, and it is very much in line with what most experienced users would do.

As for `KandB` it is a function that does not depend on its defined variables. This is akin to  saying `f(x) = y+z`. You can appreciate that no matter what value of x you introduce, your function will always return the variable independent components of y and z.

---

### The "boring" For loop way

```
perfectSquare[n_] := Sqrt[n] == Round[Sqrt[n]];

n=1; (* lets keep this constant for now *)
myList = {}; (*make an empty list*)
For[k = 0, k < 50, k++,
 For[b = 0, b < 50, b++,
  If[perfectSquare[b*n + k^2], AppendTo[myList, {k, b}]]]] (* populate the list if the selection criterion is met*)

myList (* check what is inside*)
```

[image]

---

### Using `Tables`

`For` loops are good, but try to avoid them. There are more optimised means to achieve the same result.

```
perfectSquare[n_] := Sqrt[n] == Round[Sqrt[n]];

Clear[KandB]
KandB[n_Integer] := 
 Flatten[Table[If[perfectSquare[b*n + k^2], {k, b}, Nothing], {k, 0, 50}, {b, 0, 50}], 1]

KandB[1.1] (* checking that the function returns nothing for a Real value*)
KandB[1] (* checking that that the integer value produces the desired result*)
```

---

### The "elegant" way ;)

Both [@lericr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283344/20155) and **@Carl Woll** gave beautiful answers.
The former does essentially exactly what the Table method above achieves however `Tuple` generation and the `Select` function are highly optimised within mathematica and will absolutely outperform `Table` any day but most typically not in any way that matters (we are talking about milliseconds here!). The only argument for Tables is readability for a less-experienced coder.

`FindInstance` is a very powerful function but it is more limited in my opinion as it needs to be tweaked to work as you want it to.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer is more comprehensive than anything I expected! I really appreciate you taking the time to share your knowledge

Comment: One more question: my $n$ is a huge number, and the "for loop" way ran much more quickly than the "FindInstance" way. What part of the FindInstance implementation makes for the difference in runtimes?

Comment: Although `FindInstance` is a powerful function, I do not think it is suitable for this purpose. I would go either with the Table method or the one suggested by lericr. Try both and see which one suits you better. Personally, I would have used a function that uses Select, much like lericr. 

Having said that: By using `Table` (without the `Flatten`) what is revealed very clearly is that for larger values of $n$, you have to significantly increase the scanning range of $k$ and $b$.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how you want to handle `n` exactly, but with this range of integers a brute force method works fine:

```
MyPerfectSquare[n_Integer][{k_Integer, b_Integer}] := IntegerQ[Sqrt[b*n + k^2]];
Select[Tuples[Range@50, 2], MyPerfectSquare[1]]
```

`{{1, 3}, {1, 8}, {1, 15}, {1, 24}, <<more results here>>, {22, 45}, {23, 47}, {24, 49}}`